# Function run function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help with javascript. Is it possible to do something like that:

```
variable: {
   info1: 'info1', info2: 'info2', show: false,
   someNameFunction: functionWhichIWantRun(row)
}
```

And after that when I use 
variable.someNameFunction();

That called that function what I declared functionWhichIWantRun

Comment: So calling variable.someNameFunction() will trigger function functionWhichIWantRun() with argument row ?

Comment: Yeah. Of course calling we can change. Required is that code : someNameFunction: functionWhichIWantRun(row)

Answer (score 1):

```
someNameFunction: function (column) {
  return function(row) {
           console.log('Row: '+ row +' column:'+column);
           functionWhichIWantRun(row); // you can call other functions here
         }
}
```

A simplified example:

```
let row = 1;
let variable = {
           someNameFunction: function (column) {
              return function(row) {
                        console.log('Row: '+ row +' column: '+column);
                        functionWhichIWantRun(row);
                     }
           }};

let yourRowFunction = variable.someNameFunction(2);
yourRowFunction(1)// will  print "Row: 1 column: 2"
```

Comment: It's called from another place in my code so I have to send that argument. It's maybe some option if I do `function(column) {
return function(row) {
... ` after that I can do : `someNameFunction: functionWhichIWantRun(row)`

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right, then i would do something like this:

```js
const functionWhichIWantRun = e => console.log(e);

const variable = {
  info1: 'info1',
  info2: 'info2',
  show: false,
  someNameFunction: e => functionWhichIWantRun(e)
};

variable.someNameFunction('row 01');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want, but you can try my solution

```
variable: {
   info1: 'info1', info2: 'info2', show: false,
   someNameFunction: (anotherArgs) => {
     // do something with anotherArgs
    return functionWhichIWantRun(row);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all don't see all context because I gave only a part of code (sorry for that) but resolution is:

```
variable: {
            labelKey: 'label', key: 'key', show: false,
            computedValue: someNameFunction("label")
        }

function someNameFunction(column) {
        return function (row) {
            var data = row[column];
            return data.toFixed(2);
        };
    }
```

What you think about that?